# Why am i not getting a constant delay circuit for any input size?

Tags: fpga, vhdl

I'm trying to design the following circuit:
The circuit should have a constant delay for any input size. However, when I change the input size from 10 bits to 12 bits, the circuit becomes slower.
The code might look like a full adder, but the carry out is only used for the next sum, so it doesn't propagate all the way through.
I expected the same delay, how can I solve this?
For the speed I look at Fmax shown in Quartus II.

Code 10 bits:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity generic_RBSD is
    port(
        a, b : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(9 downto 0);
        sum : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(9 downto 0);
        clk, cin : in STD_LOGIC;
        cout : out STD_LOGIC
    );
end entity;

architecture behavioral of generic_RBSD is
    signal a_s, b_s, sum_s : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(9 downto 0);
    signal couts : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(4 downto 0);
begin
    couts(0) <= ((a_s(1) xor a_s(0)) and b_s(1)) or (a_s(1) and a_s(0)); 
    sum_s(1 downto 0) <= ((a_s(1) xor a_s(0) xor b_s(1) xor b_s(0)) or ((a_s(1) xor a_s(0) xor b_s(1)) and b_s(0))) & not(a_s(1) xor a_s(0) xor b_s(1) xor b_s(0));

    couts(1) <= ((a_s(3) xor a_s(2)) and b_s(3)) or (a_s(3) and a_s(2)); 
    sum_s(3 downto 2) <= (((a_s(3) xor a_s(2) xor b_s(3) xor b_s(2)) and couts(0)) or ((a_s(3) xor a_s(2) xor b_s(3)) and b_s(2))) & (a_s(3) xor a_s(2) xor b_s(3) xor b_s(2) xor couts(0));

    couts(2) <= ((a_s(5) xor a_s(4)) and b_s(5)) or (a_s(5) and a_s(4)); 
    sum_s(5 downto 4) <= (((a_s(5) xor a_s(4) xor b_s(5) xor b_s(4)) and couts(1)) or ((a_s(5) xor a_s(4) xor b_s(5)) and b_s(4))) & (a_s(5) xor a_s(4) xor b_s(5) xor b_s(4) xor couts(1));

    couts(3) <= ((a_s(7) xor a_s(6)) and b_s(7)) or (a_s(7) and a_s(6)); 
    sum_s(7 downto 6) <= (((a_s(7) xor a_s(6) xor b_s(7) xor b_s(6)) and couts(2)) or ((a_s(7) xor a_s(6) xor b_s(7)) and b_s(6))) & (a_s(7) xor a_s(6) xor b_s(7) xor b_s(6) xor couts(2));

    couts(4) <= ((a_s(9) xor a_s(8)) and b_s(9)) or (a_s(9) and a_s(8)); 
    sum_s(9 downto 8) <= (((a_s(9) xor a_s(8) xor b_s(9) xor b_s(8)) and couts(3)) or ((a_s(9) xor a_s(8) xor b_s(9)) and b_s(8))) & (a_s(9) xor a_s(8) xor b_s(9) xor b_s(8) xor couts(3));    

    process(all)
    begin
        if (rising_edge(clk)) then      
            a_s <= a;
            b_s <= b;
            sum <= sum_s(8 downto 0) & cin;
        end if;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

Code 12 bits:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity generic_RBSD is
    port(
        a, b : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(11 downto 0);
        sum : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(11 downto 0);
        clk, cin : in STD_LOGIC;
        cout : out STD_LOGIC
    );
end entity;

architecture behavioral of generic_RBSD is
    signal a_s, b_s, sum_s : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(11 downto 0);
    signal couts : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(5 downto 0);
begin
    couts(0) <= ((a_s(1) xor a_s(0)) and b_s(1)) or (a_s(1) and a_s(0)); 
    sum_s(1 downto 0) <= ((a_s(1) xor a_s(0) xor b_s(1) xor b_s(0)) or ((a_s(1) xor a_s(0) xor b_s(1)) and b_s(0))) & not(a_s(1) xor a_s(0) xor b_s(1) xor b_s(0));

    couts(1) <= ((a_s(3) xor a_s(2)) and b_s(3)) or (a_s(3) and a_s(2)); 
    sum_s(3 downto 2) <= (((a_s(3) xor a_s(2) xor b_s(3) xor b_s(2)) and couts(0)) or ((a_s(3) xor a_s(2) xor b_s(3)) and b_s(2))) & (a_s(3) xor a_s(2) xor b_s(3) xor b_s(2) xor couts(0));

    couts(2) <= ((a_s(5) xor a_s(4)) and b_s(5)) or (a_s(5) and a_s(4)); 
    sum_s(5 downto 4) <= (((a_s(5) xor a_s(4) xor b_s(5) xor b_s(4)) and couts(1)) or ((a_s(5) xor a_s(4) xor b_s(5)) and b_s(4))) & (a_s(5) xor a_s(4) xor b_s(5) xor b_s(4) xor couts(1));

    couts(3) <= ((a_s(7) xor a_s(6)) and b_s(7)) or (a_s(7) and a_s(6)); 
    sum_s(7 downto 6) <= (((a_s(7) xor a_s(6) xor b_s(7) xor b_s(6)) and couts(2)) or ((a_s(7) xor a_s(6) xor b_s(7)) and b_s(6))) & (a_s(7) xor a_s(6) xor b_s(7) xor b_s(6) xor couts(2));

    couts(4) <= ((a_s(9) xor a_s(8)) and b_s(9)) or (a_s(9) and a_s(8)); 
    sum_s(9 downto 8) <= (((a_s(9) xor a_s(8) xor b_s(9) xor b_s(8)) and couts(3)) or ((a_s(9) xor a_s(8) xor b_s(9)) and b_s(8))) & (a_s(9) xor a_s(8) xor b_s(9) xor b_s(8) xor couts(3));

    couts(5) <= ((a_s(11) xor a_s(10)) and b_s(11)) or (a_s(11) and a_s(10)); 
    sum_s(11 downto 10) <= (((a_s(11) xor a_s(10) xor b_s(11) xor b_s(10)) and couts(4)) or ((a_s(11) xor a_s(10) xor b_s(11)) and b_s(10))) & (a_s(11) xor a_s(10) xor b_s(11) xor b_s(10) xor couts(4));

    process(all)
    begin
        if (rising_edge(clk)) then      
            a_s <= a;
            b_s <= b;
            sum <= sum_s(10 downto 0) & cin;
        end if;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

Comment: Bigger circuit = routing pressure + larger area = slower.

Comment: This level of modelling is not taking into account routing or area.  Or is the OP running synthesis/P+R on this RTL, then timing it?

Comment: How are you measuring the delay? In simulation, or in real life?

Comment: When theoretically timing circuits (for example for research purposes) do you have to take that into account? I'm trying to design the same thing as on this site: http://www.louif.com/rbin/  
When his input size increases, the delay doesn't.

Comment: In Quartus II I look at Fmax which says how fast this will run.

Comment: Does Quartus II provide path reports? If it does, look at the worst paths for the 10 and 12 bit case; see if they are similar.  This can help you get an idea of where you are bottlenecked.  It can also help you see the tool itself is timing the circuit improperly.

Comment: The worst path increases. This sounds logical because of the larger area required. However, the person at this site: http://www.louif.com/rbin/ builds the same circuit but gets constant delays for various input sizes.

Comment: I can tell the worst path increases because you told me that fmax decreases.  But if you can specifically look AT the path, you can see; is this going through the carry bit?  Or is it going through the sum bits? or is it the LSB of the sum (THIS WOULD BE WEIRD, just an example of how you use the path reports to debug).

Comment: For the 12 bit example it shows for the worst paths: from a_s[3] to sum[5]

Comment: Ideally you would want to look at each stage in the path along with the differential delays across each stage, to see if it is what you expect.  Looking at the RTL, it seems like the 10b to 12b change does not have any effect on the a_s[3] to sum[5] path.  So, as another user suggested, the increased delay is coming from the additional circuitry increasing the routing congestion; leading to less favorable vias, more crosstalk, and longer wires (probably higher fanout too but just a guess).

Comment: To debug, find the same path in both designs.  See how the change from 10b to 12b has modified this path.  You could also re-synthesize the logic and/or re-run placement and routing / timing.  Sometimes you just get stuck with a bad starting 'seed' and I am guessing Quartus II P+R is not so great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that the author of http://www.louif.com/rbin/ ran the timing report with interconnect delays set to zero, which would mean the only delays taken into account were the combinatorial logic. A real-world implementation will have different delays due to place-and-route as other commenters have pointed out.

Comment: So when you want to make the design open source and want to show the speed of the design, do you set interconnect delays to zero or not?

Comment: I would put the statistics after synthesis, including the estimated interconnect delays since this will be more useful for someone looking to implement the core.